# How to return new products and deleted products from the price history?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with 5 unique column Id, Date, Shop, Product, Price.
I can show all changes Price

```
SELECT 1 ID, '09.01.2018' "DATE", 'CandyShop' Shop, 'Pie' Product, 10 Price FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 2, '10.01.2018', 'CandyShop', 'Pie', 11 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 3, '11.01.2018', 'CandyShop', 'Pie', 10 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 4, '12.01.2018', 'CandyShop', 'Pie', 9 FROM DUAL UNION

SELECT 5, '10.01.2018', 'CandyShop', 'Candy', 9 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 6, '11.01.2018', 'CandyShop', 'Candy', 9 FROM DUAL
```

But how show new Products ? 
I want to get the row id 5. Because it was not in ChandyShop on 09/01/2018. This is a new product.

[image]

how show deleted Products ?
I want to get the row id 6. Because it was not in CandyShop on 12/01/2018, and on 11/01/2018 was. This is a deleted product.

[image]

Comment: update your question add  a proper (clear and simple) data sample and the expected  result  .. (and related  this to a question only)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve may help.

Comment: Just because you CAN use a reserved word as a column name doesn't mean you should. Try not to make it a habit - it can make life difficult eventually.

Comment: minimized the issue and removed unnecessary

Comment: What does the table look like, what columns does it contain? You're only showing us a bunch of hardcoded values and they don't make much sense.